# Chill the wort faster by applying convection (by putting it inside a laundry machine)?

Tags: wort-chiller

There are some new gadgets that allow to chill the beer as fast as 2 min. It's not rocket science, just a more efficient way to increase heat transfer by rotating the desired object (link below provides more details). So i was thinking about using this same principle by putting ice inside a laundry machine and then putting the wort inside a closed container. This would chill the wort very fast and there's the bonus of a massive aeration. Have anyone tried something similar? The more experienced brewers could point out some possible flaws in this approach? Thanks!

http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2463353/Spinchill-cools-drinks-30-seconds-SPINNING-THEM.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the principal is sound, it has major flaws for wort chilling.

Major difference is volume and temp differences. 12oz / 5gal, 75°-38° / 212°-70°

Convection works on the principal that heat transfer is at a finite rate. So give the small area cooling source more exposure by moving away what has been cooled. All brew chillers do this in different ways.

Btw I'll pass on a beer that just had the crap "spun" out of it, unless you open it for me.

You can chill a beer can in 2 minutes if you submerge in ice chest filled with ice, water, salt.

I doubt they are moving the beer much to provide added exposure, rather turning the can allowing it to come in contact with ice more, than sitting there with air space. .... Just add water.

As far as wort, while using an immersion chiller many will whirlpool the wort by various means. By pump or even drill with a wine mixer. I personally don't like my wort exposed like that.

But.. If you were to put hot wort in say a corney and give it an ice bath, it would benifiet from agitation. But... That much ice is costly, and I think there are easier ways.

I see nothing that would give added aeration, since it would be limited to the air in the sealed container.

Comment: But wouldn't be convection a linear process? In the sense that 'ok the volume is bigger' but the forces applied to the container are also bigger (and the quantity of ice etc..)? It seems that is scalable phenomena.. And to the aeration part, that would be true if the container was full..if there's a 'head' of air it would be pumped into the liquid right? Thanks for the tips evil!

Comment: @matt_zarro all the spinning is doing is making sure the can gets even chill from the ice, and some micro turbulence in the can from the resistance of the inner wall. If you pour your hot can of beer through a chilled coil, you will have ready to drink beer on the other end, this is how counter flow and plate chillers work for wort.

Comment: @matt_zarro I would suggest an experiment for you. Take a clear water bottle, remove 10% of the water so it's bouyant, put a wood tooth pick in it so it can freely float on its side. Reseal the bottle and float it in a pot, then spin it. You will find that little movement is tranfered to the water inside, making this process little more efficient than radiant cooling.

Comment: Makes perfect sense!!